# Pasar variables desde un cliente Javascript a un servidor express Node.js

Tags: nodejs, express, xmlhttprequest

Tengo un pequeño servidor express de Node.js montado en `http://localhost:5000` conectado a una base de datos que más tarde usaré.

Utilizo dos archivos principalmente: `index.html` y su Javascript de cliente, `app.js`:

```
const express       = require("express");
const app           = require("express")();
const http          = require("http").Server(app);
const mysql         = require("mysql");

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host            : 'localhost',
    user            : 'root',
    password        : '',
    database        : 'Indole_Hourglass'
});

//  MAKING SERVER
http.listen(5000, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:5000');
});

// INDEXATION
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.get('/app.js', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/app.js");
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.name);
});
```

En `index.html` solamente tengo un selector con varios nombres. Dichos nombres los mando como parámetro a una función que hace el `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
const select = document.getElementById('members');

select.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    sendVariable(e.target.value);
});

function sendVariable(name){
    let xml = new XMLHttpRequest();


    xml.open("GET", "/", true);
    xml.send(name);
}
```

Con lo que yo entiendo, creo que debería mandar a `/` la variable `name`, por tanto, el nombre que yo haya elegido en el selector.

Después en el servidor lo recogería con la última sentencia:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.name);
});
```

No sé en qué estoy fallando para poder obtener dentro del servidor dicha variable.

### Edición

Usando exactamente lo que me propuso @OscarGarcia, edité el XML para mandarlo como un formulario desde el lado del cliente:

```
function sendVariable(name){
    let xml = new XMLHttpRequest();

    let datos = new FormData();
    datos.append("name", name);

    xml.open("POST", "/", true);
    xml.send(datos);
}
```

En el lado del servidor lo recojo así:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Pero éste es el resultado:

[image: Captura de pantalla del navegador]

No manda nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que los datos enviados en el formulario sean tratado correctamente debes hacer uso de un programa intermedio (middleware), como [`express.urlencoded()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded) o [`express.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json) (gracias [@Mauricio Contreras](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/112837/mauricio-contreras)).

El programa se usa de la siguiente manera:

```
/* Para "application/json" */
app.use(express.json());
/* Para "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" */
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

Si estás usando una versión de `express` anterior a la 4.16 debes importar y hacer uso de un programa intermedio llamado [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) que será el encargado de proporcionar la misma funcionalidad.

En este caso debes importar y usar el programa de la siguiente manera:

```
/* Importamos "body-parser" si "express" < 4.16 */
const bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
/* Para "application/json" */
app.use(bodyParser.json());
/* Para "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" */
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Aunque puedes tratar datos sencillos con formularios basados en parejas `variable=valor`, te recomiendo usar datos codificados en JSON. Eso te permitirá una mayor flexibilidad a la hora de enviar información compleja (valores booleanos, matrices y/o clases anidadas, etc).

Para que se decodifiquen correctamente los datos JSON hay que enviar una cabecera HTTP en la petición indicando cómo están codificados los datos en el cuerpo de la petición:

```
xml.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Quedando el código así:

```
function sendVariable(name) {
    let xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    /* Queremos hacer uso del método POST (y no GET) */
    xml.open("POST", "/");
    /* Vamos a enviar datos codificados en JSON */
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    /* Aquí están los datos codificados en JSON */
    xml.send(JSON.stringify({name}));
}
```

Se enviará esta información:

```
{
  name: "contenido del formulario"
}
```

Ya que, por defecto, el nombre de una clave es el mismo que el nombre de la variable, por lo que no es necesario enviar un `{"name": name}`, con `{name}` es suficiente.

Comment: mandar se manda, pero hago un console.log(req.body) en el nodejs y nada mas que me pone "undefined".

Comment: Lo hago, edito la pregunta y lo ves

Comment: Editado, ya puedes ver lo que pasa, muchas gracias

Comment: Estaba probándolas, sale a las mil perfecciones lo que quería, muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Desde Express v4.16 en adelante, no se necesita incluir `body-parser` como dependencia adicional, ya que viene incorporado en Express mediante los métodos [`express.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json) y [`express.urlencoded()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded). Saludos

Comment: Hecho @MauricioContreras , he editado la respuesta con la mejora has propuesto. Y gracias de nuevo por avisarme por este cambio, lo he pasado por alto aunque se publicó hace casi 4 años :)